# NextAuth is not saving Oauth users according to MONGOOSE Schema

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a web app with nextjs, NextAuth for authentication and mongoDB with mongoose as a DB.
I've implemented two providers in [...nextauth].js path: Google and Github. also, I've connected it to the DB by the connection URL. Now what I'm looking forward to is that the users are automatically saved in accordance to the Mongoose schema that I've provided in the User model.
The problem is Google users are saved according to the schema, but Github users are not.

I have two questions:

1. is this the right way to connect NextAuth with my already connected Mongoose instance?
2. What is the explanation of this behavior; why does google users obey the schema in contrast with Github's.

What I have tried to do is trying to read the documentation in NextAuth website, but I could not find anything addressing this issue, nor I found anything explaining how to achieve this with mongoose.

config file is:

```ts
providers: [
  Providers.GitHub({
    clientId: process.env.GITHUBID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUBSECRET,
  }),
  Providers.Google({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  }),
],
database: process.env.MONGODB,
```

example of a user document from github:
[Github user document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9SS3.jpg)

user document from Google:
[Google user document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xcPr.jpg)

since reading the documentation did not help me, and there is not much content online about this topic, I would love to hear some guidance of where can I find more info about how DB connection with next-auth works and how can I understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NextAuth.js maintainer here. From your code snippet it looks like you are using the v3 version of next-auth.

In that case next-auth will save only a subset of the user profile when creating a user.

Here are those fields: https://github.com/nextauthjs/adapters/blob/main/packages/typeorm-legacy/src/models/user.js#L1-L8

In v4, the user profile will be simply determined by the profile callback of your providers. keep in mind that the user profile is created out of the profile of the provider that the user logs in with FOR THE FIRST TIME.

https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models#user

For future questions, I recommend open them on our repository either as an issue or a discussion.